# Why doesn't python tkinter label show the compute result

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to python. I want to make a score counter in my game. But the `tkinter` label can't show the correct result. It can show 1 mark if I. But if I am right in other questions. It can't show 2 marks. I want to ask any method that can show `int` and calculate result in  `.config` Here are some parts of my code.

```py
#function to count score
def count():
    global num
    num = 0
    
    if fruits_word == ans.get():
        num += 1
        score_label.config(text="%d" % num)
    else:
        num -= 1 
        score_label.config(text="%d" % num)

#create a label to show the score 
score_label = tk.Label(root, text="", font=("helvetica",16))
score_label.pack(pady=15)

#create a button to check the ans and count the score
ans_button = tk.Button(root, text="Answer", command=lambda: [answer(), count()])
ans_button.pack(pady=15)
```

Comment: You know that each time you call `count()`, `num` will be reset to 0. Move the `num = 0` before the definition of `scrore_label`

Comment: Also it isn't good practise to use `list`s inside `lambda`s to execute more than 1 function. It's much easier to read/debug if you just defined a normal python function

Comment: @TheLizzard Thanks for answer the question and the reminder. I think I know how to fix the problems.